# How can I create two conditions in if statment

Tags: javascript, if-statement

[image]
All the information is getting from DrinkAPI, and this API server did not make each array for the element sadly.. haha
I am trying to get rid of that blank box if you can see the image (on the bottom link). In the Array from API it was always null instead of this situation. Is there any way to get rid of "" by using if statement? and if you guys can make more functions efficiently please advise me!

```
function cardBuilder(xinstructions, xdrinkName, ximgUrl, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, m10, m11, m12, m13, m14, m15,
    i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10, i11, i12, i13, i14, i15) {

    var cardstring = ' <div style="width: 24rem;" class="card results-card"><img class="card-img" src="' + ximgUrl +
        '"alt="Drink"><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">' + xdrinkName + '</h5><p class="card-text">' + xinstructions + '</p>';

    var ingreds = '<ul class="list-group list-group-flush ingredients-list">';
    var fact = "";
    if (i1 != null && m1 != null ) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m1 + " " + i1 + "</li>"
    } else if (i1 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i1 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i2 != null && m2 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m2 + " " + i2 + "</li>"
    } else if (i2 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i2 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i3 != null && m3 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m3 + " " + i3 + "</li>"
    } else if (i3 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i3 + "</li>"
        }
    if (i4 != null && m4 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m4 + " " + i4 + "</li>"
    } else if (i4 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i4 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i5 != null && m5 != null ) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m5 + " " + i5 + "</li>"
    } else if (i5 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i5 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i6 != null && m6 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m6 + " " + i6 + "</li>"
    } else if (i6 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i6 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i7 != null && m7 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m7 + " " + i7 + "</li>"
    } else if (i7 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i7 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i8 != null && m8 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m8 + " " + i8 + "</li>"
    } else if (i8 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i8 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i9 != null && m9 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m9 + " " + i9 + "</li>"
    } else if (i9 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i9 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i10 != null && m10 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m10 + " " + i10 + "</li>"
    } else if (i10 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i10 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i11 != null && m11 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m11 + " " + i11 + "</li>"
    } else if (i11 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i11 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i12 != null && m12 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m12 + " " + i12 + "</li>"
    } else if (i12 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i12 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i13 != null && m13 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m13 + " " + i13 + "</li>"
    } else if (i13 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i13 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i14 != null && m14 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m14 + " " + i14 + "</li>"
    } else if (i14 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i14 + "</li>"
    }
    if (i15 != null && m15 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + m15 + " " + i15 + "</li>"
    } else if (i15 != null) {
        fact += "<li class='list-group-item'>" + " " + i15 + "</li>"
    }
    fact += "</ul>";
    cardstring += fact + "</div>";
    return cardstring;

}
```

Comment: _"I am trying to get rid of that blank box"_ . Before doing that, you may want to get rid of all this code, no? Maybe this can be written in.. 5, 6 lines maybe?

Comment: yikes that code o_O you might want to consider using rest syntax and chunking the array of arguments.  i'd say you could probably do it in less than 5

Comment: The API would be better served if it provided an array of objects, like `[{ingredient: 'vodka', measurement: 1 shot}, {ingredient: 'sugar syrup', measurement: '1/2 shot1}]` and then loop through it.

Comment: Well I m getting that drink information from DrinkAPI server.

Comment: Then that API was really poorly made Probably not by a developer

Comment: Lol I agree, I was trying to use for loop, it gives me error hahaha so I just did manually I know code that I made is very poor,but it still works so .. haha

Comment: @NakwonYoon Look at the end of [3limin4t0r's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62765125/1913729). Fully working example, using the API :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a stand-alone answer, but rather supplements the [answer of blex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62763130/3982562). To get a structure similar to the one used in the linked answer you'll have to convert the API data. This can be done in multiple ways.

Here is an example of how this can be done:

```js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping
const escapeRegExp = string => string.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');

function extractArrayProperties(obj, ...names) {
  if (names.length == 0) return [];

  const nameValues   = new Map(names.map(name => [name, []]));
  const namesPattern = names.map(escapeRegExp).join("|");
  const regex        = new RegExp(`^(${namesPattern})(\\d+)$`);

  for (const [prop, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    const [match, name, nr] = prop.match(regex) || [];
    if (!match) continue;
    const index = parseInt(nr, 10) - 1;
    nameValues.get(name)[index] = value;
  }

  const lengths = names.map(name => nameValues.get(name).length);
  const maxLength = Math.max(...lengths);
  return Array.from({ length: maxLength }).map((_, index) => {
    const entries = names.map(name => [name, nameValues.get(name)[index]]);
    return Object.fromEntries(entries);
  });
}

const drink = {
  // ...
  "strIBA": null,
  "strIngredient1": "Vodka",
  "strIngredient2": "Sugar Syrup",
  "strIngredient3": "Passion fruit juice",
  "strIngredient4": "",
  "strIngredient5": "",
  "strIngredient6": "",
  "strIngredient7": "",
  "strIngredient8": null,
  "strIngredient9": null,
  // ...
  "strInstructions": "Pour all ingredients into a glass and ...",
  "strInstructionsDE": null,
  "strInstructionsES": null,
  "strInstructionsFR": null,
  "strInstructionsZH-HANS": null,
  "strInstructionsZH-HANT": null,
  "strMeasure1": "1 shot",
  "strMeasure2": "1/2 shot",
  "strMeasure3": "Full Glass",
  "strMeasure4": "",
  "strMeasure5": "",
  "strMeasure6": "",
  "strMeasure7": "",
  "strMeasure8": null,
  "strMeasure9": null,
  // ...
};

console.log("ingredients with empty values:");
let ingredients = extractArrayProperties(drink, "strIngredient", "strMeasure");
console.log(ingredients);

console.log("ingredients without empty values:");
// Use `filter` to remove all objects with falsy strIngredient
// value. Both null and "" are considered falsy.
ingredients = ingredients.filter(ingredient => ingredient.strIngredient);
console.log(ingredients);
```

This solution loops over all (iterable) properties of an object trying to find something that matches the regex (name followed by a number). The number is converted into an integer (using base 10) and mapped to its index by subtracting 1 (your properties start with 1 not 0). The value is stored in an array saved in an lookup map under the index calculated above.

We check the longest array size when all properties are looped and create an empty array with that size. For each slot in this array we loop over all names and get the value of its index position.

```
const data = { keyB2: "e", keyA2: "b", keyA1: "a", keyB1: "d" keyA3: "c" };
extractArrayProperties(data, "keyA", "keyB");

// Will have lookup map (I'll use an object to represent a Map):
// Values are stored based on their number keyA1 has nr 1 and is
// stored at index 0, keyB2 has nr 2 and is stored at index 1.
const nameValues = {
  keyA: ["a", "b", "c"],
  keyB: ["d", "e"     ],
};

// The max length is 3. We create an array with this length and
// set the values based on the index.
[
  { keyA: "a", keyB: "d"       },
  { keyA: "b", keyB: "e"       },
  { keyA: "c", keyB: undefined },
]
```

### Demo

If we combine this with Blex's answer, we get a fully working demo, using the real API:

```js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping
const escapeRegExp = string => string.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');

// Our utility function, to extract the ingredients
function extractArrayProperties(obj, ...names) {
  if (names.length == 0) return [];

  const nameValues = new Map(names.map(name => [name, []]));
  const namesPattern = names.map(escapeRegExp).join("|");
  const regex = new RegExp(`^(${namesPattern})(\\d+)$`);

  for (const [prop, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    const [match, name, nr] = prop.match(regex) || [];
    if (!match) continue;
    const index = parseInt(nr, 10) - 1;
    nameValues.get(name)[index] = value;
  }

  const lengths = names.map(name => nameValues.get(name).length);
  const maxLength = Math.max(...lengths);
  return Array.from({
    length: maxLength
  }).map((_, index) => {
    const entries = names.map(name => [name, nameValues.get(name)[index]]);
    return Object.fromEntries(entries);
  });
}

// Card builder
function cardBuilder({ strInstructions, strDrink, strDrinkThumb, ingredients }) {
  return `
    <div style="width: 24rem;" class="card results-card">
      <img class="card-img" src="${strDrinkThumb}"alt="Drink">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">${strDrink}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">${strInstructions}</p>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush ingredients-list">
        ${
        ingredients.map(({strIngredient, strMeasure}) => 
          `<li class='list-group-item'>${strMeasure || ''} ${strIngredient || ''}</li>`
        ).join('')
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>`;
}

// Get the data from the API
fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Passion%20Fruit%20Martini')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(({ drinks: [drink] }) => {
    // Extract ingredients
    const ingredients = extractArrayProperties(drink, "strIngredient", "strMeasure")
                        .filter(ingredient => ingredient.strIngredient);
    // Create a recipe
    const recipe = {
      ...drink,
      ingredients
    };
    // Display it
    document.getElementById("drink-container").innerHTML = cardBuilder(recipe);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="drink-container"></div>
```

Comment: Really nice! +1! If you feel like it, don't hesitate to reuse my answer to mix those two. I'm not really sure that the OP will be able to do it by themselves ;)

Comment: May I edit your answer to add the fully working demo?

Comment: @blex Sure, it's getting too late for me. I'll check what you've made of it tomorrow. If you can word my explanation better you are free to do so as well.

Comment: @blex The demo looks good, but there is one thing bugging me. Elements without or with empty `strIngredient`  are now filtered out twice. Once by the `filter` method (after calling `extractArrayProperties`) and once by the template itself. Using one of the two would be enough. I would personally keep the `filter` variant and keep the template as clean as possible. Do you mind if I remove `strIngredient ? \`...\`: ''` from the view template?

Answer (score 2):

> **Look at [3limin4t0r's answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62765125/1913729)** It combines both of our answers, and there is a fully working example at the end, using the actual API.

You can greatly simplify your code. Always think **"DRY"** (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Every time you are tempted to copy/paste a variable, function, or anything else by adding a number to its name, you can be sure it's a bad idea.

Here is how I would do it:

```js
function cardBuilder({ instructions, drinkName, imgUrl, ingredients }) {
  return `
    <div style="width: 24rem;" class="card results-card">
      <img class="card-img" src="${imgUrl}"alt="Drink">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">${drinkName}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">${instructions}</p>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush ingredients-list">
        ${
        ingredients.map(x => 
          x.name
          ? `<li class='list-group-item'>${x.measurement || ''} ${x.name || ''}</li>`
          : ''
        ).join('')
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>`;
}

const recipe = {
  drinkName: 'Passion fruit Martini',
  imgUrl: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0281/1189/6681/files/pornstar-martini-1.jpg?v=1582960820',
  instructions: 'Pour all ingredients into a glass and stir',
  ingredients: [
    { name: 'Vodka', measurement: '1 shot' },
    { name: 'Sugar syrup', measurement: '1/2 shot' },
    { name: 'Passion fruit juice', measurement: 'Full Glass' }
  ]
};

document.body.innerHTML = cardBuilder(recipe);
```

```css
.card-img {
  display: block;
  width: 10rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the drinks data API (got URL from blex's comment and 3limin4t0r's answer).
Assumes ingredient properties are always in the form `str{Measure/Ingredient}{1..15}`.
Loops over array in `drinks:` property if you have multiple drinks.
Uses [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to filter null ingredients and map to li element strings in one step.

```js
function cardBuilder(drinkData) {
  const { strInstructions, strDrink, strDrinkThumb } = drinkData
  return `
    <div style="width: 24rem;" class="card results-card">
      <img class="card-img" src="${strDrinkThumb}" alt="Drink">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">${strDrink}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">${strInstructions}</p>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush ingredients-list">
        ${
          // it's always 15 ingredients maximum, extract properties str{name}{1..15}
          Array(15).fill().flatMap((x,i)=> {
            const m = drinkData[`strMeasure${i+1}`],
                  ing = drinkData[`strIngredient${i+1}`]
            return ing ?
              `<li class='list-group-item'>${m || ''} ${ing || ''}</li>` : []
              // if ingredient null filter out, else return li element string
          }).join('')
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>`;
}

// Get the data from the API
fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Passion%20Fruit%20Martini')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    // in case you query more than one drink
    for(const drink of data.drinks)
      document.body.innerHTML += cardBuilder(drink)
  })
```

Using [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) syntax, based on the code you posted:

```js
function cardBuilder(xinstructions, xdrinkName, ximgUrl, ...mi) {
    return `<div style="width: 24rem;" class="card results-card">
  <img class="card-img" src="${ximgUrl}" alt="Drink">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${xdrinkName}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">${xinstructions}</p>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush ingredients-list">
    ${
      // divide mis array in half.  filter out where both m and i are null
      // map the rest to li element strings
      mi.splice(0,mi.length/2).flatMap((m,i)=>
        mi[i] ?
         `<li class='list-group-item'>${m || ''} ${mi[i] || ''}</li>` : [])
      .join('')
    }
    </ul></div></div>`;
}

document.body.innerHTML=
  cardBuilder('instruct', 'drinkname', 'someimage.png',
  // create array, spread to params to fill in m1..m4 and i1..i5 for testing
  ...Array(30).fill(null).map((x,i)=>i%15 < 5 || i===20 ? `${i}` : null))
```

Answer (score 0):

So your code is not really good
here is mine

```js
/**
 * Dummy data 
 *
 *
 * I notice that your data is an object and every key should have pair
 * and there is no such a case when there is a key with out or with null pair
 * as well as the "Ingredient" came first and then "Measure"
 * if there is any feel free to comment down
 */

const data = {
  strIngredient1: 'Vodka',
  strIngredient2: 'Sugar Syrup',
  strIngredient3: 'Passion fruit juice',
  strIngredient4: null,
  strIngredient5: '',
  strMeasure1: '1 shot',
  strMeasure2: '1/2 shot',
  strMeasure3: 'Full Glass',
  strMeasure4: '',
  strMeasure5: null,
};

/**
 *
 * @param {*} data Object
 * @return object with two arrs { ingredient, measure }
 *
 */
const adapter = (data = {}) => {
  const cleanArray = Object.values(data).filter(
    (item) => item && item.length !== 0
  );
  const length = cleanArray.length;
  const ingredient = cleanArray.slice(0, length / 2);
  const measure = cleanArray.slice(length / 2, length);
  return { ingredient, measure };
};

console.log({ result: adapter(data) });
```

** There are some edge cases that I did not take it or see it so feel free to comment so i can maybe change the code **

Comment: Also, try to edit your backend cuz it's kind of wired your should return something like { title, value } or anything else but not like this!

Comment: the worst thing is that he's using an [existing API](https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=White%20Lady) 

Comment: This answer is based upon the the order of `Object.values` result and works with the fact that `strIngredient` takes up the first half and `strMeasure` the second half. What if there are properties like `strInstructions` in-between like shown in the image and there are other properties above and below the relevant properties?

Comment: Do you mean something like that 
{ strInstructions, strInstructionsValue }
it's going to work cuz im taken any values and assume that it's ordered so the keys first and values same as his API i'm just converting the object to array and then taken the half of it assuming that is the keys and the rest is values

Comment: Yes, you assume it's ordered and also assume you can just split it in half to get matching pairs. Take for example: `{ strIngredient1: 'Vodka', strIngredient: '...', strMeasure1: '1 shot'}` which produces `{ ingredient: ['Vodka'], measure: ['...', '1 shot'] }`